# How to override a variable in PHP that's in two functions

Tags: php, function

```
function d20() {
$rollAll = false;
$roll = rand(1,20);

    if ($rollAll == false) {    
        echo $roll; 
    }
}

function rollAll() {
$rollAll = true;
    d20();
}

rollAll();
```

I want to make it so that whenever I call the rollAll function, $rollAll will be true and it won't echo the roll. Sorry if this problem seems really stupid, but I'm new to PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Pass the variable from `rollAll` to `d20` as parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Works great.

Comment: Why would you take $rollAll = false and then check if($rollAll == false)?

Answer (score 0):

@Rizier123 Answered just i pass the variable from `rollAll` to `d20`

```
function d20($rollAll) {

$roll = rand(1,20);

    if ($rollAll == false) {    
        echo $roll; 
    }
}

function rollAll() {
$rollAll = true;
    d20($rollAll );
}

rollAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

set the variable `$rollAll` in global scope or pass as function params

```
function d20($rollAll) {
    $rollAll = false;
    $roll = rand(1,20);

    if ($rollAll == false) {    
        echo $roll; 
    }
}

function rollAll() {
    $rollAll = true;
    d20( $rollAll );
}

rollAll();
```

or

```
$rollAll = true;// or false
function d20() {
    $rollAll = false;
    $roll = rand(1,20);

    if ($rollAll == false) {    
        echo $roll; 
    }
}

function rollAll() {
    $rollAll = true;
    d20(  );
}

rollAll();
```